# How to load and launch a standard app on Google Glass

Tags: google-glass

I've written an app for the Galaxy Gear that I'd like to also use on the Google Glass with minimal changes.

Note that it works great!  The UI with the side swipe tool on the glass is just fine and *perfect* for this particular application.  What's more is I have one code base that I don't have to change for a different device.   Life is good!

But unfortunately I can't seem to launch it without running a command via ADB.

Is there a way I can make a quick change/addition to the app so I can launch it from Google Glass using the UI?

Note I'm not a registered developer, but I do have a google glass (given to me by a third party).

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It really isn't clear from your description, but do make sure that you're actually providing a good user experience for someone on Glass. Just because it "works great", doesn't necessarily mean that it will work well for how people want to use Glassware. It sounds like you think it will run well as an [Immersion](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui/immersions), so you should check that page out to make sure. Immersions are probably easiest to port, but don't always make for a very Glass-like experience, so you do need to be careful. Especially if you're not used to how the Glass experience is different than a phone or tablet experience.

One good way to launch it will probably be through the use of voice commands. See https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/voice#starting_glassware for details about setting up the resources and VOICE_TRIGGER intent. If you can use one of the existing voice commands - all the better, otherwise think about a good generic command that is probably an action verb (ie - something like "make me a sandwich" instead of the name of your app like "sandwich maker").

Comment: "Just because it "works great", doesn't necessarily mean that it will work well for how people want to use Glassware. "- fortunately, that's exactly what it means.

According to this:  "When you want to launch Glassware and have it appear in MyGlass, you must use one of these existing commands or submit a new command for approval."    I don't want to use the existing triggers (they don't make sense) but, submitting a new command for approval is very peculiar considering my app is not intended for wide distribution and I'm not a registered developer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the GDK Sneak Peek. They have tutorials that walk you through adding your own custom voice commands to the OK Glass screen. You don't need to be a registered developer, just install the GDK Sneak Peek through the SDK Manager. The [quick start](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start) is a good place to begin.